# Meson can't find static libs

Tags: meson-build

I can compile my project by running

```
g++ main.cpp -l:libpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a  -lpthread -lm -luuid
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp /usr/local/lib/libpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a  -lpthread -lm -luuid
```

But when I try adding library with either one of:

```
meson.get_compiler('cpp').find_library('libpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a')
meson.get_compiler('cpp').find_library('/usr/local/lib/libpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a')
```

I'm getting error:

> ERROR: C++ library 'libpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add 'dirs' variable even tho file is in standard /usr/local/lib path and to  remove .a extension.

```
cc.find_library('libpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu', dirs: '/usr/local/lib/')
```

Later of course lib was available inside meson and was added to executable and tested.

Comment: Another difference with the attempts in your question is that it doesn't contain the `.a` suffix